# Converting Ruby symbols to integers

Tags: ruby

I find it surprising that Ruby symbols can be typecasted to integers without errors. 
So `:a.to_i` is legal. I was wondering what is the significance of this integer, is it a unique value specific to that symbol?

Comment: `:a.to_i` throws an error for me in `irb` as well as in a Rails console; not sure how you're getting success with that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You shouldn't do this, as `Symbol#to_i` was removed in Ruby 1.9 and is thus not compatible going forward. Regardless, the [docs say this about it](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Symbol.html#method-i-to_i):

> Returns an integer that is unique for each symbol within a particular execution of a program.

It is roughly equivalent to calling [`object_id`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-object_id) on the symbol, as they both end up calling the C function `SYM2ID()`.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. For me, this was a lesson in the dangers of following deep links in Google :-) I was about to post a link to http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Symbol.html , which shows to_i as alive and kicking. Nowhere on that page (or even in the URL) does it mention that it's Ruby 1.8.4(!) doc.  Much less that it's *Ruby* doc, not ROR (as the URL implies).  You have to go to the root and look at the title to see that the site is for Ruby 1.8.4!  So, lesson learned; when following deep doc links in Google, make sure you know which version of the doc you're looking at.

Answer (score 3):

In 1.8.x symbols were immediate objects. Their implementation was fast, and, most of the time, small. But with that came a security concern regarding the lack of garbage collection.

The `#to_i` and `#to_int` methods returned a unique integer and were related to the internal implementation.

Symbols-as-immediates and the implicit and explicit integer conversions have all been removed  in 1.9.x. You can of course get the `object_id`. It's interesting that in 1.8.x `to_i` and `object_id` did not return the same number.